# Location of installed app on xcode 4.4 iOS simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode4.4

Im trying to access the .db file of an app I have installed in the simulator. Seems like xcode 4.4 has a different location. Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode places applications for simulator into the folder `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications`